Energy Supplier forced entry on a warrant issued in the name of a previous tenant
Someone moved into a property on July 1, informed the energy supplier who signed them up that day. Energy supplier had to remove a block on electricity supply as there was no electricity coming into the house when they moved in. Energy company then took money off the meter to pay the previous tenants debts, which they rectified.
On August 9 a company forced entry on behalf of the energy supplier to check the meter, apparently thinking the previous tenant had tampered with it.  They didn’t leave a warrant, just a letter saying they had a warrant.
It’s taken the person until now to get a copy of this warrant. Numerous phone calls and emails.  The person named on the warrant is a previous tenant who left the property in October of last year – the property was empty until July 1. Both companies, energy supplier and the company that forced entry, say they obtain the warrant for an empty property. The persons who forced entry acknowledged this to a neighbour and still broke in even though the property was clearly occupied.
The warrant was issued on Aug 9, 5 weeks after the person moved in on July 1.
the person has been told this may be trespass but is a civil matter? What legal recourses might they have and how should they proceed? Energy supplier have offered a miserly compensation of £100.

Did the entry cause physical damage to property, or some other indirect tangible harm? Or is this just about the abstract invasion of privacy?

Hi, they forced the lock but no damage. The person is pretty annoyed for sure, breaking into their house without any prior notification etc. Mistakes happen but still. They didn't leave a warrant in  the house,  took weeks of chasing to get it. They knew it was occupied and still forced entry. Warrant wasn't issued until Aug 9, over a month after the new tenant moved in and informed the energy supplier.... it's a pretty shambolic way of using court warrants to force entry into people's homes..

Agreed - but legal recourse tends to be based on the actual harm suffered, more so than whether the action was abstractly wrong or illegal.

it's in  England

Police say it is trespass but because they obtained a court warrant, albeit on erroneous information, it's a civil matter. Shambolic was to use court warrants to force entry into people's homes. They shouldn't be trusted with warrants as they don't care, in my opinion.

BTW, we have a rule here about not giving legal advice (i.e. "how should they proceed?"), which is why this might get closed. I sometimes bend that rule for things where a lawyer would cost more than the amount at issue, but that's about as far as I can go.

Ah ok, fair enough. Needed to word it differently.  Can you answer this tho -  basically you can go to court with erroneous information and legally break into someone's home it seems?

If its an honest mistake, yes. Arresting people for failing to do their jobs perfectly is counterproductive. OTOH knowingly lying is perjury. In between there is a grey area of negligence, but proving that is tricky as it gets in to messy issues of whether the employee or employer is really at fault. But we're getting off topic here. Questions about how to remedy the wider systemic issues belong on SE.Politics rather than Law.

Thanks for your reply.

See also my updated answer. I just remembered about the Energy Ombudsman.

Thanks, they are aware of the Ombudsman but because it's a mistake and little / no damage they are unlikely to do much. Compensation will be small regardless. It is, however, a mistake that is made repeatedly. I worked for a broadband provider many years ago and agents often signed people up without removing outstanding warrants etc attached to the property.

Oh, a final question if I may. Not leaving a copy of the warrant in the house and it taking the occupant of the house three weeks to obtain it after numerous emails and phone calls?

I know this situation is infuriating, but when you want recourse to the law you need to take a deep breath and look at the situation dispassionately. Your opinion about what the law ought to be may be perfectly justified, but right now you need to deal with the law as it is, imperfect though that may be. As Nate Eldridge says in the comments, civil recourse is generally compensation for actual harm rather than punishment. The landlord might be due compensation for the broken lock, but that's their business. If there was no other damage the tenant should probably take the £100 and move on.
Update: I should have remembered before: the tenant could raise a dispute with the Energy Ombudsman. However they say that the most common award for "time and trouble" is £50, so I wouldn't expect more than the £100 currently on offer.

If we consider a financial offer should apply to resolve your dispute, the amount will depend entirely on the complexity of the issues and the information we receive from you and the company. The most common financial award is around £50, this is sometimes referred to as a Time & Trouble Award. Find out more on our What to expect page.

